# Freeze Y-Axis label in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm trying to freeze the Y-Axis labels while scrolling. I tried to put

```js
position:fixed;
```

in style of Y-axis but doesn't seems working. Anyone came across any situation like this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is possible to keep an SVG element static the way you expect ([Keep an SVG Object static while scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192209/keep-an-svg-object-static-while-scrolling)) but if you can create the label as a seperate SVG element or for that matter a simple div and style it, it should get you the desired effect you are looking for.

Comment: Issue remain same if I create a new svg for labels and make them position :fixed it will be fixed for both direction. Ideally it should be fixed for one direction lets assume for X-Axis it should be fixed and for Y-Axis it should scroll.